# Trouble with Shopify PUT

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to modify inventory in a Shopify store, but i'm having trouble figuring it out.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: apiURL,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        "variant": {
          "id": 19358308995,
          "inventory_quantity": 100,
          "old_inventory_quantity": 496
        }
      },
      success:
           function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }

    });
```

The API URL is `'/admin/variants/19358308995.json?'`...every works fine if I use the `GET` method, but if I use `PUT` or `PUSH` I get this odd response below that basically looks like it pulls some page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"fa45dcf839","applicationID":"151","transactionName":"dl8KQUReDl4AEE1TVVhZChpXRBZaSkg=","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":20,"agent":""}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VQQUUFNS"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o||e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){try{s.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var o,i=t("ee"),a=t(14),s={};try{o=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(s.console=!0,-1!==o.indexOf("dev")&&(s.dev=!0),-1!==o.indexOf("nr_dev")&&(s.nrDev=!0))}catch(c){}s.nrDev&&i.on("internal-error",function(t){r(t.stack)}),s.dev&&i.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){r(n.stack)}),s.dev&&(r("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),r("flags: "+a(s,function(t,e){return t}).join(", ")))},{}],2:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r,o){try{d?d-=1:i("err",[o||new UncaughtException(t,e,n)])}catch(s){try{i("ierr",[s,(new Date).getTime(),!0])}catch(c){}}return"function"==typeof f?f.apply(this,a(arguments)):!1}function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}function o(t){i("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}var i=t("handle"),a=t(15),s=t("ee"),c=t("loader"),f=window.onerror,u=!1,d=0;c.features.err=!0,t(1),window.onerror=r;try{throw new Error}catch(l){"stack"in l&&(t(8),t(7),"addEventListener"in window&&t(5),c.xhrWrappable&&t(9),u=!0)}s.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){u&&(d+=1)}),s.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){u&&(this.thrown=!0,o(n))}),s.on("fn-end",function(){u&&!this.thrown&&d>0&&(d-=1)}),s.on("internal-error",function(t){i("ierr",[t,(new Date).getTime(),!0])})},{}],3:[function(t,e,n){t("loader").features.ins=!0},{}],4:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){}if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&window.performance.getEntriesByType){var o=t("ee"),i=t("handle"),a=t(8),s=t(7);t("loader").features.stn=!0,t(6);var c=NREUM.o.EV;o.on("fn-start",function(t,e){var n=t[0];n instanceof c&&(this.bstStart=Date.now())}),o.on("fn-end",function(t,e){var n=t[0];n instanceof c&&i("bst",[n,e,this.bstStart,Date.now()])}),a.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){this.bstStart=Date.now(),this.bstType=n}),a.on("fn-end",function(t,e){i("bstTimer",[e,this.bstStart,Date.now(),this.bstType])}),s.on("fn-start",function(){this.bstStart=Date.now()}),s.on("fn-end",function(t,e){i("bstTimer",[e,this.bstStart,Date.now(),"requestAnimationFrame"])}),o.on("pushState-start",function(t){this.time=Date.now(),this.startPath=location.pathname+location.hash}),o.on("pushState-end",function(t){i("bstHist",[location.pathname+location.hash,this.startPath,this.time])}),"addEventListener"in window.performance&&(window.performance.clearResourceTimings?window.performance.addEventListener("resourcetimingbufferfull",function(t){i("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.clearResourceTimings()},!1):window.performance.addEventListener("webkitresourcetimingbufferfull",function(t){i("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.webkitClearResourceTimings()},!1)),document.addEventListener("scroll",r,!1),document.addEventListener("keypress",r,!1),document.addEventListener("click",r,!1)}},{}],5:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){for(var e=t;e&&!e.hasOwnProperty(u);)e=Object.getPrototypeOf(e);e&&o(e)}function o(t){s.inPlace(t,[u,d],"-",i)}function i(t,e){return t[1]}var a=t("ee").get("events"),s=t(16)(a),c=t("gos"),f=XMLHttpRequest,u="addEventListener",d="removeEventListener";e.exports=a,"getPrototypeOf"in Object?(r(document),r(window),r(f.prototype)):f.prototype.hasOwnProperty(u)&&(o(window),o(f.prototype)),a.on(u+"-start",function(t,e){if(t[1]){var n=t[1];if("function"==typeof n){var r=c(n,"nr@wrapped",function(){return s(n,"fn-",null,n.name||"anonymous")});this.wrapped=t[1]=r}else"function"==typeof n.handleEvent&&s.inPlace(n,["handleEvent"],"fn-")}}),a.on(d+"-start",function(t){var e=this.wrapped;e&&(t[1]=e)})},{}],6:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("ee").get("history"),o=t(16)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window.history,["pushState","replaceState"],"-")},{}],7:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("ee").get("raf"),o=t(16)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["requestAnimationFrame","mozRequestAnimationFrame","webkitRequestAnimationFrame","msRequestAnimationFrame"],"raf-"),r.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=o(t[0],"fn-")})},{}],8:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",null,n)}function o(t,e,n){this.method=n,this.timerDuration="number"==typeof t[1]?t[1]:0,t[0]=a(t[0],"fn-",this,n)}var i=t("ee").get("timer"),a=t(16)(i);e.exports=i,a.inPlace(window,["setTimeout","setImmediate"],"setTimer-"),a.inPlace(window,["setInterval"],"setInterval-"),a.inPlace(window,["clearTimeout","clearImmediate"],"clearTimeout-"),i.on("setInterval-start",r),i.on("setTimer-start",o)},{}],9:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){d.inPlace(e,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-",s)}function o(){var t=this,e=u.context(t);t.readyState>3&&!e.resolved&&(e.resolved=!0,u.emit("xhr-resolved",[],t)),d.inPlace(t,v,"fn-",s)}function i(t){w.push(t),h&&(g=-g,b.data=g)}function a(){for(var t=0;t<w.length;t++)r([],w[t]);w.length&&(w=[])}function s(t,e){return e}function c(t,e){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}t(5);var f=t("ee"),u=f.get("xhr"),d=t(16)(u),l=NREUM.o,p=l.XHR,h=l.MO,m="readystatechange",v=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"],w=[];e.exports=u;var y=window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var e=new p(t);try{u.emit("new-xhr",[e],e),e.addEventListener(m,o,!1)}catch(n){try{u.emit("internal-error",[n])}catch(r){}}return e};if(c(p,y),y.prototype=p.prototype,d.inPlace(y.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",s),u.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,e){r(t,e),i(e)}),u.on("open-xhr-start",r),h){var g=1,b=document.createTextNode(g);new h(a).observe(b,{characterData:!0})}else f.on("fn-end",function(t){t[0]&&t[0].type===m||a()})},{}],10:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=this.params,n=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var r=0;l>r;r++)t.removeEventListener(d[r],this.listener,!1);if(!e.aborted){if(n.duration=(new Date).getTime()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){e.status=t.status;var i=o(t,this.lastSize);if(i&&(n.rxSize=i),this.sameOrigin){var a=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");a&&(e.cat=a.split(", ").pop())}}else e.status=0;n.cbTime=this.cbTime,u.emit("xhr-done",[t],t),c("xhr",[e,n,this.startTime])}}}function o(t,e){var n=t.responseType;if("json"===n&&null!==e)return e;var r="arraybuffer"===n||"blob"===n||"json"===n?t.response:t.responseText;return i(r)}function i(t){if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;if("object"==typeof t){if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;if(!("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData))try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(e){return}}}function a(t,e){var n=f(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+":"+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}var s=t("loader");if(s.xhrWrappable){var c=t("handle"),f=t(11),u=t("ee"),d=["load","error","abort","timeout"],l=d.length,p=t("id"),h=t(13),m=window.XMLHttpRequest;s.features.xhr=!0,t(9),u.on("new-xhr",function(t){var e=this;e.totalCbs=0,e.called=0,e.cbTime=0,e.end=r,e.ended=!1,e.xhrGuids={},e.lastSize=null,h&&(h>34||10>h)||window.opera||t.addEventListener("progress",function(t){e.lastSize=t.loaded},!1)}),u.on("open-xhr-start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},a(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),u.on("open-xhr-end",function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),u.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,e){var n=this.metrics,r=t[0],o=this;if(n&&r){var a=i(r);a&&(n.txSize=a)}this.startTime=(new Date).getTime(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(o.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||o.called===o.totalCbs&&(o.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof e.onload))&&o.end(e)}catch(n){try{u.emit("internal-error",[n])}catch(r){}}};for(var s=0;l>s;s++)e.addEventListener(d[s],this.listener,!1)}),u.on("xhr-cb-time",function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),u.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,e){var n=""+p(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),u.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,e){var n=""+p(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),u.on("addEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&u.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),u.on("removeEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof m&&"load"===t[0]&&u.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),u.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof m&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=(new Date).getTime()))}),u.on("fn-end",function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&u.emit("xhr-cb-time",[(new Date).getTime()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}},{}],11:[function(t,e,n){e.exports=function(t){var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split("://");!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname);var i=!e.protocol||":"===e.protocol||e.protocol===n.protocol,a=e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port;return r.sameOrigin=i&&(!e.hostname||a),r}},{}],12:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){return function(){o(t,[(new Date).getTime()].concat(a(arguments)),null,e)}}var o=t("handle"),i=t(14),a=t(15);"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=NREUM);var s=["setPageViewName","addPageAction","setCustomAttribute","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit"],c=["addPageAction"],f="api-";i(s,function(t,e){newrelic[e]=r(f+e,"api")}),i(c,function(t,e){newrelic[e]=r(f+e)}),e.exports=newrelic,newrelic.noticeError=function(t){"string"==typeof t&&(t=new Error(t)),o("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}},{}],13:[function(t,e,n){var r=0,o=navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/);o&&(r=+o[1]),e.exports=r},{}],14:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e){var n=[],r="",i=0;for(r in t)o.call(t,r)&&(n[i]=e(r,t[r]),i+=1);return n}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],15:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(0>o?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=r},{}],16:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){return!(t&&"function"==typeof t&&t.apply&&!t[a])}var o=t("ee"),i=t(15),a="nr@original",s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;e.exports=function(t){function e(t,e,n,o){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,s,c;try{a=this,r=i(arguments),s="function"==typeof n?n(r,a):n||{}}catch(u){d([u,"",[r,a,o],s])}f(e+"start",[r,a,o],s);try{return c=t.apply(a,r)}catch(l){throw f(e+"err",[r,a,l],s),l}finally{f(e+"end",[r,a,c],s)}}return r(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[a]=t,u(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function n(t,n,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<n.length;c++)s=n[c],a=t[s],r(a)||(t[s]=e(a,f?s+o:o,i,s))}function f(e,n,r){if(!c){c=!0;try{t.emit(e,n,r)}catch(o){d([o,e,n,r])}c=!1}}function u(t,e){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var n=Object.keys(t);return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,{get:function(){return t[n]},set:function(e){return t[n]=e,e}})}),e}catch(r){d([r])}for(var o in t)s.call(t,o)&&(e[o]=t[o]);return e}function d(e){try{t.emit("internal-error",e)}catch(n){}}return t||(t=o),e.inPlace=n,e.flag=a,e}},{}],ee:[function(t,e,n){function r(){}function o(t){function e(t){return t&&t instanceof r?t:t?s(t,a,i):i()}function n(n,r,o){t&&t(n,r,o);for(var i=e(o),a=l(n),s=a.length,c=0;s>c;c++)a[c].apply(i,r);var u=f[v[n]];return u&&u.push([w,n,r,i]),i}function d(t,e){m[t]=l(t).concat(e)}function l(t){return m[t]||[]}function p(t){return u[t]=u[t]||o(n)}function h(t,e){c(t,function(t,n){e=e||"feature",v[n]=e,e in f||(f[e]=[])})}var m={},v={},w={on:d,emit:n,get:p,listeners:l,context:e,buffer:h};return w}function i(){return new r}var a="nr@context",s=t("gos"),c=t(14),f={},u={},d=e.exports=o();d.backlog=f},{}],gos:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n){if(o.call(t,e))return t[e];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return t[e]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r){o.buffer([t],r),o.emit(t,e,n)}var o=t("ee").get("handle");e.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){var e=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:a(t,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=t("gos");e.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(t,e,n){function r(){if(!m++){var t=h.info=NREUM.info,e=u.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&e){c(l,function(e,n){t[e]||(t[e]=n)});var n="https"===d.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp;h.proto=n?"https://":"http://",s("mark",["onload",a()],null,"api");var r=u.createElement("script");r.src=h.proto+t.agent,e.parentNode.insertBefore(r,e)}}}function o(){"complete"===u.readyState&&i()}function i(){s("mark",["domContent",a()],null,"api")}function a(){return(new Date).getTime()}var s=t("handle"),c=t(14),f=window,u=f.document;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:f.XMLHttpRequest,REQ:f.Request,EV:f.Event,PR:f.Promise,MO:f.MutationObserver},t(12);var d=""+location,l={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-918.min.js"},p=window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),h=e.exports={offset:a(),origin:d,features:{},xhrWrappable:p};u.addEventListener?(u.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1),f.addEventListener("load",r,!1)):(u.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",o),f.attachEvent("onload",r)),s("mark",["firstbyte",a()],null,"api");var m=0},{}]},{},["loader",2,10,4,3]);</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shopify &raquo; Please log in</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/touch-icons/touch-icon-192x192-840b11274adbc510a1db23976759bd31ceee84ddbb36478d494a3a2cf19b5ae6.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/favicon-4425e7970f1327bc362265f54e8c9c6a4e96385b3987760637977078e28ffe92.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/touch-icons/mobile-startup-564eed49b6c483b80796f529e05b4bf1d54e9cd9beeb0bb89b10d3c6a2282ea6.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/touch-icons/icon-114x114-precomposed-79d1c57f01b233f016319dc4048d90524e9ce252c058a306ef9db2216ab26911.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/touch-icons/icon-72x72-precomposed-584c35aa679456ab4e2f1cd971191498d7fecf7321b4ded8bae5c5a2c51176e3.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/touch-icons/icon-57x57-precomposed-49c0927bd56de30bc28439aed87097b7c8e41f2bb4f00661f01a00729c2a1b77.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/dialog-047a27dad0275f7f8b1dec198cce61c721ae435d9fc526f742cd9af5eedbc89f.css" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-BHon2tAnX3+LHewZjM5hxyGuQ12fxSb3Qs2a9e7byJ8=" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <noscript class="no-js">In order to use the Shopify admin you need to enable Javascript. <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">Learn how to enable Javascript</a>.</noscript>
    <main role="main" id="dialog-alternate">
      <div class="login-form">
  <h1 class="dialog-heading">Raffo Store</h1>
  <h2 class="dialog-subheading">Log in to manage your store</h2>

  <form action="/admin/auth/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7tMxCWkw24spLPb1pXM+fa2OqsKneFLf/itLSIECXW7uB6VtqLcoqJLWVD/kWvoKhM+1LSZJMooEd6UpKKBEPg==" />
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="login-container">

        <div class="lform dialog-form">
          <div class="require-cookies status dialog-status">
            <p>Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sign-in-form" class="lform dialog-form">

          <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" id="redirect" />

          <div id="login">
            <div class="dialog-input-container clearfix">
              <input type="email" name="login" size="30" id="login-input" class="dialog-input " value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Email" />
              <label for="login-input" class="visuallyhidden">Email</label>
              <i class="ico dialog-ico ico-email"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dialog-input-container clearfix">
              <input type="password" name="password" size="16" id="password" class="dialog-input " spellcheck="false"  placeholder="Password" />
              <label for="password" class="visuallyhidden">Password</label>
              <i class="ico dialog-ico ico-password"></i>
              <div class="forgot-password-container">
                <a class="forgot-password tooltip tooltip-bottom" id="forgot-password" aria-label="Forgot your password?" href="/admin/auth/recover">
                  <span class="tooltip-container"><span class="tooltip-label">Forgot your password?</span></span>
                  <i class="ico dialog-ico ico-forgot-password"></i>
</a>              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- /#login -->
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log in" class="dialog-btn" />
        </div> <!-- /#sign-in-form -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="remember-me">
      <input name="remember" type="checkbox" id="remember_checkbox" value="1">
      <label for="remember_checkbox" class="inline">Remember me</label>
    </div>

</form>
  <script>
//<![CDATA[

    if ( typeof window.analytics !== 'undefined' ) {
      window.analytics.trackForm($('[action="/admin/auth/login"]')[0], 'login', {
        category: 'login',
        subdomain: "raffo-store.myshopify.com"
      });
    }

    if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
      $('.require-cookies').show();
    }

//]]>
</script>
</div>

    </main>

    <footer role="contentinfo" id="footer">
      <a target="_blank" class="ico ico-shopify-bag" href="//www.shopify.com">
        <span class="helper--visually-hidden">Shopify.com</span>
</a>    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/admin/auth-1b2825339906181d969da6db6a9b9de93558c69c92a62edbdb5857735c0a8b6a.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-GyglM5kGGB2Wnabbapud6TVYxpySpi7b21hXc1wKi2o="></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(["_setAccount","UA-82702-18"]);_gaq.push(["_addDevId","o5cUG"]);_gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker",true]);_gaq.push(["_setDomainName",".myshopify.com"]);_gaq.push(["_setAllowHash",false]);_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",2,"PlanName","basic",2]);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview","\/admin\/auth\/login"]);</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var analytics = window.analytics = window.analytics || [];
    var config = {"Trekkie":{"appName":"admin","defaultAttributes":{"shopId":12643983}},"LastShop":{}};

    if (analytics.initialize) {
      return;
    }

    analytics.methods = [
      'trackSubmit',
      'trackClick',
      'trackLink',
      'trackForm',
      'pageview',
      'identify',
      'initialize',
      'group',
      'track',
      'ready',
      'alias',
      'page',
      'once',
      'off',
      'on'
    ];

    analytics.factory = function(method){
      return function(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.unshift(method);
        analytics.push(args);
        return analytics;
      };
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < analytics.methods.length; i++) {
      var key = analytics.methods[i];
      analytics[key] = analytics.factory(key);
    }

    analytics.load = function(config){
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.async = true;
      script.src = '//cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/trekkie.' + config.Trekkie.appName + '.min.js';
      var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);

      analytics.initialize(config);
    };

    analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION = '3.0.1';
    analytics.load(config);
    analytics.page();
  })();
</script>


  <script>
// Important The user is logged in, set to user_id; else, set to ''
var _user_id = '12643983'

// IMPORTANT! Set to a unique session ID for the visitor's current browsing session.
var _session_id = 'b3358a69949798c6292de53e6f583d6f46692dd93d9cfd3498cf38baf87e2eb4';

var _sift = window._sift = window._sift || [];

// IMPORTANT! Insert your JavaScript snippet key here!
_sift.push(['_setAccount', 'dba93e6d07']);

_sift.push(['_setUserId', _user_id]);
_sift.push(['_setSessionId', _session_id]);
_sift.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>

<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/sift_tracking-4470e2bd915f0e51a83b9c0b000349d985d7ccaa02268390b6ea86d39f153fb3.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-RHDivZFfDlGoO5wLAANJ2YXXzKoCJoOQtuqG058VP7M="></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously this isn't the response i'm looking for, but I can't figure out what i'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to review the shopify api..., ajax not work for this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create private app keys and use those for authentication. Simple GETs from the browser work for information that is reasonably public. The public cannot update your inventory :-)

Comment: I had a feeling that was it! However how do I pass the keys in the put? I don't see anything in the docs about it. Do I need to use the JS SDK?

Comment: Different technologies uses different placements of the keys. Check for "header authentication basic" for the platform you'll be using your app on.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Example URI should look like this for anyone checking this question: `https://{APIKey}:{Password}@your-store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json`

Comment: You can also do `    var cred = new Buffer("{APIKey}":"{Password}").toString('base64');
    
    var headers = {Authorization: "Basic "+cred, "Content-Type": "application/json"};`

Comment: @ElliottMcNary, that format doesn't always work, for example in nodejs you need to explicitly mention the authentication in headers and in C# you specifically need to convert APIKey and Password to base64

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to cookies in your browser. Try to reset the cookies. I had the same problem when POSTing queries in Postman Chrome app. I was advised to change it to the stand-alone Postman app https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/can-t-cancel-order-from-the-api-but-can-from-the-admin-portal-453257
(because of the cookies problem) and that really worked.

Setting the private app keys in not enough.

And also set the header:

Content-Type: application/json